# Remove object_id from to_s call

Tags: ruby, string, class, object

I am currently editing a class' to_s method to make it puts out something prettier. At the last line, the `object_id` is include `#<Profile:0x007fde5aadd280>`. Any way to remove this object_id from the output without doing so explicitly after calling to_s

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own `#inspect` method.

```
class Foo
  def inspect
    "<#%s>" % self.class
  end
end

Foo.new # => <#Foo>
```

Read the documentation [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect)

> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of obj. By default, show the class name and the list of the instance variables and their values (by calling inspect on each of them). ***User defined classes should override this method to make better representation of obj. When overriding this method, it should return a string whose encoding is compatible with the default external encoding.***